# How to specify Git config path

Tags: git, ubuntu, pm2

I have a `~/.gitconfig` file, and I have installed pm2 which creates a folder called `~/config/`.

After that, Git assumes that pm2's `~/.config/` folder is where it will find it's settings (spoilers: it's not).

How do I tell Git to stop looking in `~/.config/` and just use good old `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: Does `~/.config/git/config` exist?

Comment: @Collin Nope. The `.config` folder only contains `/configstore/` (pm2 stuff).

Comment: Weird, so looking at the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES) it seems to say git will only use the `.config` directory if the git config file exists within it. In fact, that's exactly what it does on my machine.

Comment: Yep. And it fails if it is unable to check whether the git config file exists within (because of permissions). That may be undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlassian had the answer. Just `chown` the folder to allow Git to look through the folder, then Git will find nothing, and correctly move along to `.gitconfig`

```
sudo chown -R my_user:my_user ~/.config
```

The folder should be owned by the user anyway, seeing as how it is in my user's home folder.
Source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/permission-denied-on-git-config-file-314447088.html

Answer (score 2):

Typing `man git config` has a section called FILES that lists the locations of all the system files. The global Git config file is in `~/.gitconfig`, but there's also a "system" config file, that's usually in `/etc/gitconfig.`

Comment: I solved it by chowning the folder, but this looks like it would work as well since Git would then consider `/etc/gitconfig/` first.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file must be `.gitconfig`.

What you can do it to set an alias `~/.config/` to point to `~/.gitconfig/`

Comment: Thing is, I still need the `.config` folder for pm2.